# How to get the output of a T-SQL PRINT command as string in a .net application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

How can I retrieve a string generated by the PRINT t-sql command of SQL Server in my .net application

Example Microsoft SQl Server Management Studio :

[image]

Comment: If its really necessary (i.e you cannot use a select/return value, OUT param) use a [`SqlInfoMessageEventHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlinfomessageeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I've tried not working d.
How did Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio do it?

Comment: That's the way to do it, if its not working then you must not be using it correctly.  There are many examples out there E.g. http://www.tf3604.com/2016/03/01/capturing-output-from-sql-server-using-c/

Answer (score 7):

In order to retrieve these message, you can use the [`InfoMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage(v=vs.110).aspx) event available on the `SqlConnection` class.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
    conn.InfoMessage += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{e.Source}-{e.Message}");
    };
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("PRINT 'Hello World'", conn))
    {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```